# Probability of 3 events

Tags: probability

Suppose that A, B, and C are events such that $A \bigcup B \bigcup  C = \Omega$ , $A \bigcap B = \emptyset$, $B \bigcap C = \emptyset$, P(A)=0.3, P(B)=0.7, P(C)=0.5.
 Calculate: 
a) $P(A \bigcap C)$  and
b) $P(A \bigcup C)$

Comment: What is $\Theta$?

Answer (score 1):

Or another way, going the other way round:
b) Since $A \cap B = B \cap C = \emptyset$, we get that 
$$
1 = P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A \cup C) + P(B),
$$
which yields $P(A \cap C)$ and then via
$$
P(A \cup C) = P(A) + P(C) - P(A \cap C)
$$
you get a). However, the numbers seem to be wrong in your example. For example, if you calculate $P(A \cup C)$, this is less than $P(C)$ which is impossible as $C \subset A \cup C$ or in the other answer if you calculate $P(A \cap C)$ this is bigger than $P(A)$ which is also impossible. So something seems to be wrong here.